# Edit external stylesheet with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a web design template and I would like to edit the stylesheet based on a radio button selection using query.

Please see attached fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/2MKjv/1/

What i'm trying to achieve is, if i select blue, it will find the EXTERNAL stylesheet and the class .container and change the background to blue. So if i manually edit the stylesheet after, the changes will be saved, is this possible?

It's just a very basic html:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="radio" name="colours" value="female" checked> red
  <input type="radio" name="colours" value="female">blue
</div>
```

& CSS

```
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
html, body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:red;
}
```

Comment: You can't edit server files in Javascript, you need do it from a server script, which you could invoke via AJAX.

Comment: jsfiddle is using a style tag; if you want to edit the stylesheet itself you may want to use a different sscce site

Comment: +1 to Barmar for AJAX reference. You should send it with AJAX and use PHP to edit server files. Any changes made with JS, will only affect the current session.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you learn something new everyday, can anyone guess what my next question will be lol

Comment: @Dan Take a look at the links I provided in my answer below. I'm guessing your question is how to achieve this all with AJAX and PHP. Read through the links, try some things, and if you need help but can't find a similar question that was already asked, post a specific question so we can help you further.

Comment: @NateKibler thanks, been taking a look at the links and I have to admit, i've not got a clue where to start. I'm using wordpress so I figure i've got to manually connect to the database which seems easy enough but that's where i'm lost. I suppose i've got a lot more readying ahead of me.

Comment: Yes, reading is always good. I'm not familiar with Wordpress, but if you'd like to use PHP to connect to a MySQL database, try [this tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php). If my answer helped you arrive to your solution, please mark it as the correct answer so others know that you have been helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't with jQuery alone.

Longer answer: jQuery is an extension of JavaScript, which by its nature, is run on the client side in their browser. Thus, you can't directly change any files that are stored on the server. You can, however, use [jQuery's AJAX feature](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to easily access some server-side script that could change the file, such as PHP.

In PHP, for example, you could use [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/function.file-put-contents) to write to a file to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/2MKjv/2/

It's a simply soluction.

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function(){
    var color = $(this).attr('data-color');

    $('.container').css({'background': color});
});
```

Comment: But you can't save this. You can use PHP and MySQL to do this wich the best way.